# Set Task Manager file name

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Application name in Task Manager’s Applications Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365789/set-application-name-in-task-managers-applications-tab)

It seems that we can  use different name for some application in Task Manager.

How to do it for WPF application?

> i.e. Visual Studio exe file is "devenv.exe" and u can see it under
>   Task Manager like "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (32 bit)"

Thank you!

Comment: @DominicKexel Wrong comment. It is not the same. i.e. Visual Studio exe file is "devenv.exe" and u can see it under Task Manager like "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (32 bit)"

Comment: Your profile description could have helped you quite a lot...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. I found it.

It is the field "Title" under "Assembly Information."

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to do.  Task Manager reads it from the file version resource, an unmanaged resource embedded into a program.  The equivalent in .NET is the FileVersionInfo.FileDescription property.

Unmanaged resources are embedded by the C# compiler with the /win32res compile option.  There should always be at least 3 of them in a C# program, the version info, a manifest that declares it compatible with UAC and an icon.  If you don't specify it yourself then the IDE auto-generates this.  It uses the [assembly:] attributes that are specified in AssemblyInfo.cs, the [AssemblyTitle] attribute matters in this case.

Easiest way to set it is with Project + Properties, Compile tab, Assembly Information button, Title field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using visual studio I believe its Project>Properties>Application>Assembly name

Comment: May be... But i.e. Visual Studio exe file is "devenv.exe" and u can see it under Task Manager like "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (32 bit)"