# How to have a different process name (for current process) name in task manager?

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

How can I set the current process's name in task manager?
For example, I have "application.exe", when I run it, it shows application.exe in task manager. I want to change this without having to change the current executable's name or spawning a child process. This is an application without any GUI.

I know some programs already do this, like notepad++.

[image: Notepad++ in Task Manager]

Comment: Create an invisible window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Task Manager file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604777/set-task-manager-file-name)

Answer (score 3):

Task Manager shows the File Description / Assembly Title of the executable file.

You can change that via the user interface in Visual Studio by going to the project properties of the executable project:

[image]

Or change the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` in your executable project:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Fancy Application Name")]
```

This string will then be shown in Task Manager:

[image]